# How to programmatically retrieve the child drawable of an InsetDrawable that was defined in XML

Tags: android, xml, drawable

how can I get the drawable object defined within an InsetDrawable by using `android:drawable` or even by having an inner `<bitmap android:src>` tag programmatically?

I want to have a LevelListDrawable as child of the InsetDrawable and need to call `setLevel(int)` on it. InsetDrawable.getCurrent() returns the InsetDrawable object itself, but not the child drawable.

Because I have multiple references to this inset drawable  defined in XML files, I cannot use IDs to identify the drawable, but need to retrieve the right drawable by `getCurrent()` and `getDrawable()` method calls. For StateListDrawable, LevelListDrawable, LayerDrawable this approach works well. But how can I do it for InsetDrawables?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.java/) for the class.

There is no way to get the drawable. It's contained inside the static inner class InsetState and there is no getter method for it. Classes in the same package (android.graphics.drawable) 
could potentially access it, but as it is you're out of luck.

Comment: Use the force! While reflection is pretty cool, you have no guarantee that they won't change things up and break your code... it's a risky business.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but using reflection is too risky for me.

Comment: I just found a workaround that works for me: Just use a LayerDrawable instead of an InsetDrawable. With that you can have padding definitions within an `item` tag as well, called a little bit different (e.g. `android:top`) and with a `.getDrawable(0)` call the inner drawable can be get. But be careful, because the layout behavior is slightly different. The padding seems to have no influence to other drawables, like it is for InsetDrawable, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029270/unexpected-layerdrawable-behavior-when-drawing-layers-containing-insetdrawables)